# Brute Forcing - StackOverflowError

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I am creating a brute force program the just runs through possible strings, (for education purposes only of course), and I have a problem...
When I do :

```
package com.arinerron.tools.Tools;

/**
 *
 * @author aaron
 */
public class BruteForce {
    public static char[] CHARSET_ALPHABET = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'};

    private char[] CHARSET = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    private int LENGTH = 3;

    private int sofar = 1;

    public BruteForce(char[] charset, int length) {
        this.CHARSET = charset;
        this.LENGTH = length;
    }

    public String bruteForce() {
        go("");
        return "";
    }

    private void log(String t) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }

    private void go(String w) {
        for(int i = 0; i != this.CHARSET.length; i++) {
            String txt = w + this.CHARSET[i];
            if(sofar < LENGTH) {
                go(txt);
            } else {

            }
            System.out.println(txt);
        }
        sofar++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BruteForce bf = new BruteForce(BruteForce.CHARSET_ALPHABET, 2);
        bf.bruteForce();
    }
}
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
    at com.arinerron.tools.Tools.BruteForce.go(BruteForce.java:32)
    at com.arinerron.tools.Tools.BruteForce.go(BruteForce.java:34)
    at com.arinerron.tools.Tools.BruteForce.go(BruteForce.java:34)
    at com.arinerron.tools.Tools.BruteForce.go(BruteForce.java:34)
    at com.arinerron.tools.Tools.BruteForce.go(BruteForce.java:34)
    at com.arinerron.tools.Tools.BruteForce.go(BruteForce.java:34)
    at com.arinerron.tools.Tools.BruteForce.go(BruteForce.java:34)
    at com.arinerron.tools.Tools.BruteForce.go(BruteForce.java:34)
    at com.arinerron.tools.Tools.BruteForce.go(BruteForce.java:34)
    at com.arinerron.tools.Tools.BruteForce.go(BruteForce.java:34)
    at com.arinerron.tools.Tools.BruteForce.go(BruteForce.java:34)
    at com.arinerron.tools.Tools.BruteForce.go(BruteForce.java:34)
    at com.arinerron.tools.Tools.BruteForce.go(BruteForce.java:34)
    at com.arinerron.tools.Tools.BruteForce.go(BruteForce.java:34)
```

Why? It doesn't look that hard for the computer to handle... :\

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you increment the *sofar* variable at the wrong place. The condition that starts a new recursion will always be true and this causes the stack to overflow.

Think of when the *sofar* variable gets incremented. Try moving `sofar++;` to just before the recursive call `go(txt)` and see what happens.

So:

```
private void go(String w) {
    for(int i = 0; i != this.CHARSET.length; i++) {
        String txt = w + this.CHARSET[i];
        if(sofar < LENGTH) {
            sofar++;
            go(txt);                
        } 
        System.out.println(txt);
    }        
}
```

On a side note: why are you returning an empty string from the `bruteForce()` method? Wouldn't void make more sense.

Comment: Yeah it would, it's just later I'm going to implement it. For now, just an empty string! :)

Comment: Wait so to get the program to work, I should move sofar++; to after go(txt);

Comment: @FnafServer no, you have to increment before, otherwise you'll never get out of the recursion

Comment: It works, except the output isn't right... It only changes the last character... :(

Comment: @FnafServer Maybe the print statement should be in another place too? I can't say as I don't know what the output should be, but at least it doesn't crash anymore.